# Convergence of gamma function

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to find the values of $x$ for which $$\int_0^1 t^{x-1}e^{-t} dt$$ converges.

Now I have tried to tackle this by parts, which gives $$\int_0^1 t^{x-1}e^{-t}=\left[-t^{x-1}e^{-t}\right]_0^1+(x-1) \int_0^1 e^{-t}t^{x-2}$$In order to evaluate $\left[-t^{x-1}e^{-t}\right]_0^1$, we require $x-1>0$, so that we don't divide by $0$ or get $0^0$.

So my answer would be $x>1$. However, I was reading some notes on this, and an argument was that $$\int_0^1 e^{-t}t^{x-1} dt\leq \int_0^1 1 \cdot t^{x-1} dt$$ $$=\left[\frac{t^x}{x}\right]_0^1$$ which is okay if $x>0$. The notes conclude that the integral is valid for $x>0$. So I am wondering which inequality is right. Why do I not get the region of validity for $0<x<1$ from my calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if $x\geq 1$, then the function being integrated is a continuous function on $[0,1]$, so clearly the integral exists. And your argument shows that.

However, you make the mistake of saying that if $x<1$, then the interval does not exist, simply because **one** of the two sumands is infinite. This is false, because the "infinity"-ness of $$[-t^{x-1}e^{-t}]_0^1$$ can possibly get cancelled out by the infinityness of $$\int_0^1 e^{-t}t^{x-2}$$

---

Remember, if $f$ is not defined at $a$, but is defined on $(a,b]$, then by definition, $$\int_a^b f(t)dt=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{a+\epsilon}^bf(t)dt$$
which means you are essencially always operating with limits, and you can only conclude that the sum of limits is the limit of sum if you know all the limits in question exist.

Essencially, your argument is equivalent to saying that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n$$ does not exist because $\frac1n=n+\frac1n-n$ and therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = \lim_{n\to\infty} n - \lim_{n\to\infty}(n-\frac1n)$$

and, since $\lim_{n\to\infty} n$ doesn't exist, the entire limit does not exist. Clearly, a fallacious argument.

---

The argument in the notes, on the other hand, is correct.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

The gamma function is defined as $$\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$ with functional equation $$\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$$ We now see that $$\Gamma(s)=\frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{s}$$ so $\Gamma(s)$ converges for $s>0$.
Splitting the Gamma Function into $$\int_{0}^1 t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt +\int_{1}^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$ we see that the second integral has no poles on [1,$\infty$] regardless of $s$, and so $$\int_{0}^1 t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$ only converges for $s>0$

Comment: What is a pole?

Comment: Where the function is undefined or goes to $\pm\infty$