# Show that this is not Rienmann integrable for $x\leq 0$

Tags: real-analysis

> Consider $$\int_0^1 e^{-t} t^{x-1}dt$$ Show that it is not Rienmann integrable for $x\leq 0$.

I know/have already proven that is integrable for $x>0$. However, I am having a hard time constructing step functions for the lower and upper sum that illustrate that it cannot be Rienmann integrable.

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

I would like to show this using upper/lower Darboux sums.

Comment: Hint: when $t \to 0$, how does $e^{-t}$ behave? Also, when $x\leq 0$, how does the integrand behave as $t \to 0$?

Comment: It tends to $\infty$, and I think also the integrand does too, since for fixed $x \leq 0$, $ t^{x-1}$ is bounded in [0,1]? Although, there is a problem with t=0 and x= 0...

Comment: Be careful: $e^{-0} = e^{0}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502942/convergence-of-gamma-function/2502968?noredirect=1#comment5169653_2502968

Comment: @aleden Hi, I asked that question. But I am specifically looking here to prove divergence from the lower sum/upper sum definition of the Rienmann integral.

Comment: Is it necessary that you do the proof by definition of upper/lower Darboux sums, or is the method left up to the solver?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502942/convergence-of-gamma-function)

Comment: It is, because my previous question says to find the values for it is integrable and now it says to find the values for which is it Rienmann integrable. I suspect I need to use the Darboux sums and I have no idea how to

Comment: There's no need to use Darboux sums for this type of problem: just track down the asymptotic behavior of $e^{-t}t^{x-1}$, and use the fact that $e^{-t}t^{x-1} \sim t^{x-1}$ when $t \to 0$, and that the integral $\int_{0}^{1} t^{x-1}$ diverges for $x \leq 0$.

Comment: Actually $f(t) = e^{-t}t^{x-1}$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ for $x<1.$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$e^{-t}t^{x-1}\ge e^{-1}t^{x-1}$$
and the last function has a divergent integral.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. But I want to show this using the Darboux sums.

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Why do you need to show it via Darboux sums, it would probably be enough to see if [Lebesque's Criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) applies on the interval.

Comment: We haven't studied any of Lebesque's criteria yet, so it is not right to use it without having proved it.

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove For which functions can you form the upper Darboux sum?